# path for grep including escaped spaces

Tags: bash, grep, escaping

I did my best to make sure this is not a duplicate and found many similar topics here, but none seems to really address my problem here:

In a bash script I'm trying to use something like

```
path="$HOME/dir\ with\ spaces"    
grep pattern "$path/file"
```

This returns:

```
grep: /home/user/dir\ with\ spaces/file: No such file or directory
```

Why is that?
When I try the same in the terminal it works ok as soon as I use the path without quotes. But as soon as I use quotes, I get the same error. Of course in the script I need the quotes or else the escaping doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write like this, the `\` will get included in the string:

> ```
> path="$HOME/dir\ with\ spaces"
> ```

And then when you use `$path` as a filename, the shell will look for a file with `\` in the name, not only the spaces.

Write like this:

```
path="$HOME/dir with spaces"
```

Alternatively:

```
path=$HOME/dir\ with\ spaces
```

In other words, you can escape spaces in path names in two ways:

- Use `\` to escape the spaces one by one
- Enclose the entire string within double-quotes or single-quotes